# Turn off multi-line editing on Up/Down arrow in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

The latest version of Visual Studio "helpfully" added new functionality to its multi-line editing capabilities (Alt+Shift+Up/Down) that allow you to move the cursor vertically after you've expanded the cursor.  Previously, and this is how it works in Notepad++ and others as well, hitting Up or Down (no metas) will collapse the multi-line and give you a single-line cursor again.

I don't understand how moving the multi-line cursor vertically is useful, and it's rather annoying to discover that hitting Up and typing something ended up creating a bunch of characters I don't want in other lines. The only thing that collapses the cursor is Escape.

Is there an option to disable this and return back to the original behavior of Up/Down = collapse?

Comment: This default behaviour is extremely annoying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is called "[multi-caret selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2022#multi-caret-selection)".  You can revert to the old behavior under Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced and select the option **Use box selection**.